# Typescript pass fields throught constructor with type checking

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to pass fields object throught the constructor's object :

```
new Alloy({ name: "foo" })
```

The issue is that's the type is not checked :

```
export class Alloy {

    name!: string

    constructor(data: Partial<Alloy>) {
        Object.assign<Alloy, Alloy>(this, {
            name: data.name!
        });
    }
}
```

For example, see my second test (`is mandatory`) do not throw an error, and it's expected to :

```
import { Alloy } from "./Alloy"

describe("Alloy", () => {

    const defaultParams = {
        name: "Foo bar"
    }

    describe("has a name", () => {
        test("is a string", async () => {
            const alloy = new Alloy({ ...defaultParams, name: "Foo bar" })

            expect(alloy.name).toEqual("Foo bar")
            expect(typeof alloy.name === "string").toBeTruthy()
        })

        // this test is failing
        test("is mandatory", async () => {
            const t = () => {
                const alloy = new Alloy({ ...defaultParams, name: undefined })
            };
            expect(t).toThrow(TypeError);
        })
    });
})
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: because i'm passing a undefined name, I'm expecting to have an error. Then the second test failed, because it's not throwing anything (`Received function did not throw`)

Comment: Name is not required in your model `Alloy`. You need to set the type of name string and don't make it optional :)

Comment: How do that ? `name!: string` the ! marker set the name as required ? no ?

Comment: @Xero name! skips null/undefined checking for this property - which is force-bypassing the behaviour you want

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the definition of your class. By adding the `!`s, you're telling TS that you know that it won't be undefined/null - not that it's required.

You'll never get runtime errors like this - because all type checking occurs at compile time, not at runtime.

If you declare the class like this then you will allow TS to show you the problems:

```
export class Alloy {

    name: string

    constructor(data: Partial<Alloy>) {
        Object.assign<Alloy, Alloy>(this, {
            name: data.name,
        });
    }
}
```

Now you get errors to tell you that name isn't guaranteed to be undefined, and that data.name could also be undefined so is not assignable to a required property.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is not working, I get `Property 'name' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.ts(2564)`

Comment: @Xero - yes - but I thought your question was "why is this not failing"? This now fails because it's incorrect. How are you intending this to work? If you want all the properties to be defined, you shouldn't initialise it with a Partial. If you can provide some more information on expected behaviour I can try to come up with a solution

Comment: You can either: A. check if name is set and throw a runtime error if it isn’t. B. require that name is set in your constructor arguments by replacing Partial<Alloy> with Partial<Alloy> & {name: string}.